# javascript onclick event, add +1 and -1 in quantity product

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I tried to make some code with Jquery when I click the `+` button, the field quantity increases, and when I press the `-` button the quantity decreases, and it works

But when I press another color and size, the field jumps no longer +1, it does +2

[image: first round work]

[image: second round jump]

However, this method still doesn't work for me. Can anyone help? Thank you.

```js
$('#partQuantity').on('click', "#plus" + data[k].Id, function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var quantityInput = document.getElementById('qua' + data[k].SkuSizeId); // Assuming 'SkuSizeId' is the correct property

  if (quantityInput) {
    var currentValue = parseInt(quantityInput.value) || 1;

    if (currentValue < data[k].OnHand) {
      quantityInput.value = currentValue + 1;
    }
  }
});

$('#partQuantity').on('click', "#minus" + data[k].Id, function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var quantityInput = document.getElementById('qua' + data[k].SkuSizeId); // Assuming 'SkuSizeId' is the correct property

  var currentValue = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
  if (currentValue > 1) {
    quantityInput.value = currentValue - 1;
  }

});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML.

Comment: *But when I press another color and size* - it's quite likely that this the code causing the problem.   Or more likely a combination of the two.   Please include a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.   See [mcve].

Comment: Add a `console.log(...)` inside each of your event handlers - if you get two console outputs (look for the (2) on the left if you haven't turned this option off in the console) then your event handlers have been initiated twice and the event is running twice.

Comment: $ is not defined - please include your html, and the jquery `<script>` link in it, so that the stack snippet works.

Comment: @absolutelynotthethe the snippet won't work as it's missing the relevant HTML - see first comment.  I've converted it to a code block to remove the confusion.

Comment: Is this code part of a loop? What is `data[k]`?

Comment: Instead of using a loop, It would be better to delegate a listener to all elements with the same class. It can use DOM navigation or element attributes to find the related quantity element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's doubling because of the way your event handlers are bound (maybe it's triggering twice?)

In jQuery you can chain methods, which mitigates doing something twice. Also you could use a class to handle the selector, rather than trying to keep track of an explicit id.

```
$('#partQuantity')
  .on('click', '.plus', function() {})
  .on('click', '.minus', function() {});
```

That being said, here is a crude example of another way you can clamp a + / - display between 1 and available quantity:

```js
$('.qty')
  .on('click', '[data-adjust]', function() {
    let qty = {
      adjust: parseInt(this.dataset.adjust),
      cur: parseInt($('.qty [data-constraint="cur"]').text()),
      max: parseInt($('.qty [data-constraint="max"]').text())
    };

    $('.qty .display').text(Math.min(Math.max(1, qty.cur + qty.adjust), qty.max));
  });;
```

```css
.qty{
align-items: center;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 2rem 4rem 2rem;
user-select: none;}

.qty div{
align-items: center;
border: 1px solid gray;
display: flex;
height: 2rem;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;}

.qty [data-adjust]{
cursor: pointer;}

.qty .available{
border: none;
grid-column: span 3;}
```

```html
<div class="qty">
  <div data-adjust="-1"><span>-</span></div>
  <div class="display" data-constraint="cur"><span>1<span></div>
  <div data-adjust="1"><span>+</span></div>  
  <div class="available"><span data-constraint="max">7</span><span>available</span></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```